# Font size changing on UILabel

Tags: ios, uilabel

I have created an UILabel in a custom collection view cell with a fond size of 17. But during run time I'm only getting a height of 16.0. This works if I manually re-assign it during run time. And yes, I have set the height constraint of the label.

Been stuck with this for hours.. :(

Comment: Happened to me once when I had conflicting constraints and my height constraint broke and with adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth set to yes, it automatically adjusted

Answer (score -1):

Have you set the below method to return 16.0? If so, you should either set it to 17.0 or a cell class property that is 17.0.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Comment: It is a collection view